# UIScrollView Not Sizing Properly In Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm trying to convert part 1 of the [Ray Wenderlich UIScrollView Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift) into Autolayout with universal devices. I currently have a `UITableView`  embedded in a Navigation Controller, connecting a `UIViewController` of class `ViewController` with a `UIScrollView` (of no custom class). The Navigation Controller has an opaque navigation bar and no toolbar. The Attributes for the `UIViewController` can be seen in the first image in the album below.

[Image Album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGdQz.jpg)

With just the four storyboard constraints (outlined below), my view looked like the second image in the album, with the `scrollView`'s frame size at an incorrect `600x536`. To fix this, I decided to add the constraints again at runtime, in `viewDidLoad()` in `ViewController.swift`. I now have 8 total constraints:

- 4 constraints on the storyboard:

  - `scrollView.top` = `topLayoutGuide.bottom`
  - `scrollView.bottom` = `bottomLayoutGuide.top`
  - `scrollView.leading` = `superView.leading`
  - `scrollView.trailing` = `superView.trailing`
- 4 contraints in `ViewController.swift`:

  - `scrollView.top` = `topLayoutGuide`
  - `scrollView.bottom` = `view.bottom`
  - `scrollView.leading` = `view.leading`
  - `scrollView.trailing` = `view.trailing`

With these constraints, before zooming, my view now looks like the third album image, with `scrollView`'s frame size at a still incorrect `375x667`. After zooming, my view is correct, looking like the fourth album image, with `scrollView`'s frame size at a correct `375x603`. A few other notes:

- `self.topLayoutGuide.length = 0`. Shouldn't it be 64? 20 from the status bar and 44 from the navigation bar?
- Removing the storyboard constraints leads to the same problem as not having programmatic constraints. Why do the storyboard constraints still need to be there?
- I have tried both pure and mixed approaches, neither of which have solved this problem.
- As well as disabling `Adjust Scroll View Insets`, `Extend Edges Under Top Bars`, and `Extend Edges Under Opaque Bars` in the storyboard (see first image), I am also disabling them in code, to no avail.
- I can't use insets because the frame of the `UIScrollView` changes after zooming.

**How can I get the `UIScrollView` to be a constant, proper size?**

Thank you.

#### class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Reset the layout
    scrollView.needsUpdateConstraints()
    scrollView.setNeedsLayout()
    scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()

    //Set storyboard settings just in case
    scrollView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false

    //Manually added constraints at runtime
    var constraintTS = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: topLayoutGuide, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    var constraintBS = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    var constraintLS = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    var constraintRS = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(constraintTS)
    view.addConstraint(constraintBS)
    view.addConstraint(constraintLS)
    view.addConstraint(constraintRS)

    println(scrollView.frame.width)
    println(scrollView.frame.height)

    //Original Ray Wenderlich code
    let image1 = UIImage(named: "photo1")!
    imageView = UIImageView(image: image1)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: image1.size)
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    scrollView.contentSize = image1.size

    let scrollViewFrame = scrollView.frame
    let scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.width / scrollView.contentSize.width
    let scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.height / scrollView.contentSize.height
    let minScale = min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.zoomScale = minScale

    centerScrollViewContents()
}

func centerScrollViewContents() {
    let boundsSize = scrollView.bounds.size
    var contentsFrame =  imageView.frame

    if contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.width) / 2.0
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0
    }

    if contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.height) / 2.0
        println("boundsSize.height: \(boundsSize.height)")
        println("boundsSize.width:  \(boundsSize.width)")
        println("contentsFrame.origin.y: \(contentsFrame.origin.y)")
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0
    }

    imageView.frame = contentsFrame
}

func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
}

func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    centerScrollViewContents()
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    println(self.topLayoutGuide.length)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Thanks to [Working with Top Layout Guide in UIScrollView through Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23508957/2490299). I didn't think a UIScrollView would make `topLayoutGuide` behave differently, but apparently it does. Also turns out I didn't need to set the constraints; `scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()` does the trick! My scrollView is now a constant 375x667, removing the resizing issue and giving `self.topLayoutGuide.length` = 64. This allows me to center the view vertically by subtracting `self.topLayoutGuide.length` in `centerScrollViewContents()`. I also call `centerScrollViewContents()` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`. Here's my new code:

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Redo constraints at runtime
    scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()

    //Original Ray Wenderlich code
    let image1 = UIImage(named: "photo1")!
    imageView = UIImageView(image: image1)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: image1.size)
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    scrollView.contentSize = image1.size

    let scrollViewFrame = scrollView.frame
    let scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.width / scrollView.contentSize.width
    let scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.height / scrollView.contentSize.height
    let minScale = min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.zoomScale = minScale
}
func centerScrollViewContents() {
    let boundsSize = scrollView.bounds.size
    var contentsFrame =  imageView.frame

    if contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.width) / 2.0
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0
    }

    if contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.height - self.topLayoutGuide.length) / 2.0
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0
    }

    imageView.frame = contentsFrame
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    println(self.topLayoutGuide.length)
    centerScrollViewContents()
}
```

All other functions have not been changed.