# How to open a view controller in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a table view and when the cell is tapped in table, I'm pushing another view controller
as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
 PriceChart *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pricechart"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

 }
```

Now My question is: the view controller I'm going to show should be in land scape mode but it is in portrait mode.

Another question is how to open different view controllers when different cell is tapped. I tried it using `indexpath.row` but is there any other way using `storyboard`?

Answer (score 1):

```
shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations, preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

The above methods don't get called of a `UIViewController` if they are inside any  `UINavigationController`. If these methods are declared inside `UINavigationController` then they will get called.

For solving this make a class lets call it `OrientationEnabledNavigation`, it is a subclass of `UINavigationController`. Then implemented `shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations, preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` methods inside `OrientationEnabledNavigation`.

**OrientationEnabledNavigation.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OrientationEnabledNavigation : UINavigationController

@end
```

**OrientationEnabledNavigation.m**

```
#import "OrientationEnabledNavigation.h"

@interface OrientationEnabledNavigation ()

@end

@implementation OrientationEnabledNavigation

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
//    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Then if you want to use navigation controller in your project then use `OrientationEnabledNavigation`. After that if you implement `shouldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations, preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` these method inside your viewcontroller then they will get called.

The in you viewcontroller implement these:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Another way is that add some code beginning of your app delegate:

For `UITabBarController`

```
@implementation UITabBarController (AutoRotationForwarding)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if ([self.selectedViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotate)]) {
        return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if ([self.selectedViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientations)]) {
        return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
    else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}

@end
```

For `UINavigationController`

```
@implementation UINavigationController (AutoRotationForwarding)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if ([self.topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotate)]) {
        return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}

-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if([self.topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientations)])
    {
        return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

@end
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can force to landscape

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In class which is in landscape mode:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
// return orientation that you want
//return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
return YES;
//return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

If you use UINavigationController, you should inherit your navigationController from UINavigationController and implement

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.. 
This demo has solved my problem...

https://github.com/alloy/ForceOrientationTest

Answer (score 0):

You can force an orientation refresh as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22084634/1049134) and the other answers in that question.

As for the second question, just populate a `UITableViewController` with either static cells or dynamic prototype cells. Then control+drag from the cell to another view controller in your Storyboard. You'll have the same Push/Modal/Custom actions that show up for buttons.

Comment: i tried it but by this way i can show same controller for all cells.

Comment: Do you mean you can push or that you can't?